# msdeploy.exe throws "Unable to find specified file"

Tags: webdeploy

I am trying to deploy a web package to my IIS Server.  My package folder has the following contents:

Directory of C:\WebDemos\FileUpload

```
12/19/2023  09:38 AM    <DIR>          .
12/19/2023  10:09 AM    <DIR>          ..
12/19/2023  08:14 AM             4,022 bpfileupload.deploy-readme.txt
12/19/2023  10:01 AM            15,058 bpfileupload.deploy.cmd
12/19/2023  08:14 AM               144 bpfileupload.SetParameters.xml
12/19/2023  08:14 AM               621 bpfileupload.SourceManifest.xml
```

1    2/19/2023  08:14 AM         7,849,821 bpfileupload.zip

Per the readme.txt I execute the following command line:
bpfileupload.deploy.cmd /T /M:WIN-VASU2TUE0R7 /G:True

I was able to capture the actual command line that was being executed which is:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='C:\WebDemos\File Upload\bpfileupload.zip' -dest:auto,computerName="WIN-VASU2TUE0R7",includeAcls="False",tempAgent="True" -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -skip:objectname='dirPath',absolutepath='obj\\Release\\Package\\PackageTmp\\App_Data$' -skip:objectname='dirPath',absolutepath='Demo\ Uploader\\App_Data$' -setParamFile:"C:\WebDemos\File Upload\bpfileupload.SetParameters.xml" -whatif
```

My SetParameters.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="Demo Uploader" />
</parameters>
```

When I run the script it returns "Unable to find specified file".

My user has full permissions to to folder where the script resides.  Any help here will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Matt Paisley